# java GC and console

Tags: java

Just to understand, what is happening I done the below code:

```
public class Loopp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i=1;
        while(true) {
            Employee e = new Employee("MyName", i);
            i++;
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

But on console I do not see any output, but when I run this in **debug** mode, then it prints 2 3 4 ..
I understand that gc is activated again and again to collected the garbage objects, but does that clear console also :|

**Edit:**

As per the answer , it worked for me, and I learned a new thing today

```
System.out.println(i + " ");
System.out.flush();
```

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with garbage collection. GC does not even _know_ about a console, let alone clear it.

Comment: Are you running in any IDE?

Comment: Have you run it on command prompt?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using `print` without `flush`. Only `println` has *autoflushing* semantics.

Add `System.out.flush()` to your code.

Comment: Doesn't it flush when the program exits?

Comment: @mostruash This program never exits

Comment: @mostruash But you *are* right in another way: when the buffer fills up, and it should rather quickly given the code, then the flush happens anyway. However, since that may be quite a lot of output, the console may delay showing it.

Comment: On that note, is there any limit on the buffer size before it finally prints? I know it would be OS-specific if there were, but I'm wondering if there's any documentation about how big it is for the different OS flavors since it's ultimately just using standard out descriptors.